# Python Logging - Extra Output?

Tags: python, logging

I'm building a Logger class for a project, and I have specified an output, which presents logs in the format

```
2017-05-16 13:29:17,573 - Geospatial - INFO - Using only New York Geolocations
2017-05-16 13:29:18,325 - Server - INFO - Successfully launched AppLogs consumer
```

But the console is also printing this line, which I do not want.

`INFO:Server:Successfully launched AppLogs consumer`

The logger is printing the correct output to the output file. I thought maybe it had something to do with the handlers, but I wasn't able to block it with the modifications I tried. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here's the class:

```
import os
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

class Logger():

    #Types of Logs: debug, info, warning & error

    def __init__(self, name):

        with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
            cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)

        if 'file_name' in cfg['logging']:
            file_name = cfg['logging']['file_name']
        else:
            file_name = 'application'

        if 'folder_name' in cfg['logging']:
            folder_name = cfg['logging']['folder_name']
        else:
            folder_name = 'logs'


        if not os.path.exists('{}/'.format(folder_name)):
            os.makedirs(folder_name)
        file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                                 '{}/{}.log'.format(folder_name, file_name))

        name = name.replace('.log','')

        if name.lower() in cfg['logging']:

            if cfg['logging'][name.lower()] == 'info':
                level = logging.INFO
            elif cfg['logging'][name.lower()] == 'debug':
                level = logging.DEBUG
            elif cfg['logging'][name.lower()] == 'error':
                level = logging.ERROR
            else:
                level = logging.DEBUG
        else:
            level = logging.DEBUG

        logger = logging.getLogger('{}'.format(name))
        logger.setLevel(level)

        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        handler = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        handler.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(level)

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        logger.addHandler(ch)

        self._logger = logger

    def get(self):
        return self._logger
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of:

> ch = logging.StreamHandler()

as this creates an handler that outputs things on console, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler

Remove it, and the associated `addHandler` call, to remove output on console if you do not want it.